# unlink multiple files in a C linux program

Tags: c, linux, posix, unlink, rm

I am trying to simulate the behavior of linux commandline command

```
rm a1*.txt
```

using either wildcards or regular expressions, inside a C program (linux gcc).

Is there a standard way of doing that?

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages!

Comment: Take a look at [`glob()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/glob.html)

Comment: One is a subset of the other. I would prefer a POSIX C solution, but if there is nothing simple, I wonder if C++ has a standard one.

Comment: @mousomer I don't think that's true any more, in as much as idiomatic C is no longer always valid C++.

Comment: @unwind, I know. That's irrelevant to my question. I don't want to go there. Didn't intend on starting a C vs C++ flame war.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on a POSIX system, you can use [`glob()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) to expand such a pattern.

Then, of course, use the standard [`remove()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) function to do the deletion.

Comment: Nice. I hadn't come across glob before. I was thinking it'd be a call to nftw, which I suppose might still be a good bet if this was ever to expand to a recursive removal!